# Why does a single row get retrieved from a dataframe as a dictionary, and not as a Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the below code:

```
import pandas as pd

activities = {
    'id': ['34343', '11', '1234'],
    'map': [
        {'id': 5743, 'summary_polyline': 343434},
        {'id': 95},
        {'id': 86},
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(activities)
has_polyline = df['map'].map(lambda x: True if x.get('summary_polyline') else False)
df = df.set_index(has_polyline) 
df = df.loc[True]

print(df['map'])
```

What gets printed is a dictionary:

```
{'id': 5743, 'summary_polyline': 343434}
```

But if there were more than two rows that have the polylines in them:

```
    import pandas as pd

    activities = {
        'id': ['34343', '11', '1234'],
        'map': [
            {'id': 5743, 'summary_polyline': 343434},
            {'id': 95, 'summary_polyline': 111}, # second True row
            {'id': 86},
        ]
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(activities)
    has_polyline = df['map'].map(lambda x: True if x.get('summary_polyline') else False)
    df = df.set_index(has_polyline) 
    df = df.loc[True]

    print(df['map'])
```

A `Series` object would have been printed:

```
 map
    True    {'id': 5743, 'summary_polyline': 343434}
    True         {'id': 95, 'summary_polyline': 111}
    Name: map, dtype: object
```

Why is that so and how can I **always** get `Series`, even if there is only one `True` row? I need consistent output as I don't know beforehand how many `True` rows there will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, your problem starts when you use an index to indicate whether or not a row `has_polyline`.
When you look by index, pandas assume that you are looking for a specific row, so it will return that row alone as a series. looking for a specific column will now give you the object in that cell.
If multiple rows have the same index, pandas has no choice but to return them all, so looking for a column will now give you a series.

You can use the following syntax to avoid this behavior:

```
import pandas as pd

activities = {
    'id': ['34343', '11', '1234'],
    'map': [
        {'id': 5743, 'summary_polyline': 343434},
        {'id': 95},
        {'id': 86},
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(activities)
has_polyline = df['map'].map(lambda x: True if x.get('summary_polyline') else False)
print(df[has_polyline]['map'])
```

Here, you're telling pandas "take all the rows for which `has_polyline` is True, and give me the `'map'` column of the df you get.